# Find number of checkboxes with the same id that are checked

Tags: jquery

I have a horrible problem trying to see if any of the checkboxes using a certain id is clicked.

An example of the checkboxes are

```
<input name="our_list[]" value="AB1-A" type="checkbox" class="listheck" id ="AB1 OB 90xs r5Ty" />
<input name="our_list[]" value="AB1-B" type="checkbox" class="listheck" id ="AB1 OB 90xs r5Ty" />
<input name="our_list[]" value="AB1-C" type="checkbox" class="listheck" id ="AB1 OB 90xs r5Ty" />
<input name="our_list[]" value="AB1-D" type="checkbox" class="listheck" id ="AB1 OB 90xs r5Ty" />
<input name="our_list[]" value="AB2-A" type="checkbox" class="listheck" id ="AB2 OB 90xs r5Ty" />
<input name="our_list[]" value="AB2-B" type="checkbox" class="listheck" id ="AB2 OB 90xs r5Ty" />
<input name="our_list[]" value="AB2-C" type="checkbox" class="listheck" id ="AB2 OB 90xs r5Ty" />
<input name="our_list[]" value="AB2-D" type="checkbox" class="listheck" id ="AB2 OB 90xs r5Ty" />
```

and my latest script is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.listheck').click(function(){
        var thisID    = $(this).attr('id');
        var checked = $('#'+thisID+':checkbox:checked').length;
        alert(thisID+" Number checked:" + checked);
    }); 
});
</script>
```

The alert shows the id of the checkbox but the checked value is always 0 even when they are checked

I know that each element id should be unique and that may be the problem or it may be that the id has spaces in it but this is for a system that is already been developed by someone else and unfortunately I cant change the way it works.

Ive tried lots of different solutions here but none seem to do what I need.

Any assistance appreciated

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique. use the class names for that. ex: class="listheck AB1"

Comment: Why do multiple elements have the same id?

Comment: And why do you need to look them up by id? You've already got the element that was clicked with `$(this)`. Just check it if is checked.

Comment: Lack of uniqueness in IDs is going to cause you problems when scripting against them. You should push whoever is approrpiate to get the original system fixed since it will make your life a lot easier in the long run. In the short term there are going to be workarounds for everything you find but its going to make all your code a lot messier and harder to maintain than it should be.

Answer (score 1):

ID's should be unique. But if you cannot change the code this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.listheck').click(function(){
        var checkedTotal = {};
        $(".listheck").each(function(index, el) {
            var id = $(el).attr("id");
            if ( $(el).prop("checked") ) {
                if ( !checkedTotal[id] ) {
                    checkedTotal[id] = 1;
                }
                else {
                    checkedTotal[id] = checkedTotal[id]+1;
                }
            }
        });
        var msg = "";
        for ( var p in checkedTotal ) {
            msg += p + " # Checked: " + checkedTotal[p] + "\n";
        }
        alert(msg);
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking up by id. Try to find something else that groups those check boxes. try finding by the `name` attribute instead of `id`. Jquery is using a js method that is expecting only one element to have an specific id, as per the spec. So it's probably only ever returning the first one. Use another selector other than id if you can't fix the structure.

Answer (score 0):

That code will only check the first element with a given `id` (since `id` is unique for elements).
In fact, if you try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FuDA3/) you get the result that only one checkbox is currently checked.

You can use instead the `.each` method to loop through all the currently checked checkboxes and count how many of them have a given `id`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.listheck').click(function(){
    var thisID    = $(this).attr('id');
    var checked = 0;
    $('.listheck:checked').each(function(index, val) {
        if ($(this).attr('id') == thisID) {
            checked++;
        }
    });
    alert(checked + ' checkbox with id ' + thisID + ' are checked');
    }); 
});
```

See a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8sJs/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[id="AB1 OB 90xs r5Ty"]').length
```

Comment: Could you explain about your solution.

Comment: if you want to find number of checkbox with same id , use tag [id=""].length

Example with alert:
alert($('[id="AB1 OB 90xs r5Ty"]').length);

Result: 4